# Is it possible to cache user credentials per terminal session in git?

Tags: git, git-config

We are able to save user credentials for a specified time period with

```
git config --global credential.helper cache --timeout <the time to save the credentials in seconds>
```

but is it possible to instead have the credentials save per individual terminal session? What I mean by this is I want my credentials to be stored indefinitely for the current open terminal, but as soon as I restart the terminal or open a new session, I would have to log in again and cache for that specific terminal session. Is this possible? I find the timer method slightly annoying.

Answer (score 0):

The [git credential cache](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-credential-cache) caches credentials in memory, but that means any new terminal session would access that shared memory.

So you would need to write you [own `git-credential-xxx` helper](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitcredentials#_custom_helpers) in order to limit the scope to a terminal session.